# Entity Framework many-to-many conditional join

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Right now I have 3 tables: User, Roles, and User_Roles for the many-to-many association. I want to create a search function that takes in a list of RoleIDs and return Users with that role. But **if the RoleID list is empty, it should return all Users**.

This is what I have so far..

```
public static List<User> SearchUser(List<int> roleIDs)
{
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        var users = (
            from u in db.Users
            join ur in db.User_Role
                on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
            join r in roleIDs
                on ur.RoleID equals r
            select u
            ).Distinct().ToList();
    }
    return userList;
}
```

but I can't figure out a way to conditionally join to User_Role only when roleIDs is not empty.

I also tried this but it didn't work.

```
var users = (from u in db.Users
             from r in roleIDs
             join ur in db.User_Role
                 on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
             where roleIDs.Count == 0 || ur.RoleID == r
             select u
                ).Distinct().ToList();
```

Is it possible to have a conditional join in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat each case separately.

```
public static List<User> SearchUser(List<int> roleIDs)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        if (roleIDs.Count == 0)
        {
             return db.Users.ToList();
        }

        var users = (
            from u in db.Users
            join ur in db.User_Role
                on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
            join r in roleIDs
                on ur.RoleID equals r
            select u
            ).Distinct().ToList();

        return users;
    }
}
```

You can simplify the join as follows if the join table is not mapped as separate entity.

```
public static List<User> SearchUser(List<int> roleIDs)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        if (roleIDs.Count == 0)
        {
             return db.Users.ToList();
        }

        var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => roleIDsContains(r.Id)))
            .Distinct().ToList();

        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eranga. Using if statements crossed my mind but in reality, the function will be able to take multiple list parameters to further filter the search. With all the combinations of empty lists and non-empty lists, using the if statement will start to get messy quick. That's why I thought a conditional join would be the most elegant way.

Comment: I marked your response as the answer because technically, if statements was the way to go. I just changed the logic. See my posted response.

Answer (score 0):

My biggest was concern keeping the code maintainable as new search criteria is added and to minimize the database calls. I ended up using if statements but didn't load it from the database till the very end. This resulted in one large sent query. I forced the database call by calling `.ToList()` at the end.

```
public static List<user> SearchUser(List<int> roleIDs, List<int> hobbyIDs)
{
    List<User> Users = new List<User>();
    IQueryable<User> tempUsers = null;
    using (var db = new DBContent())
    {
        tempUsers = db.Users;

        if (roleIDs.Count > 0)
        {
            tempUsers = from u in tempUsers
                        join ur in db.User_Role on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
                        join r in roleIDs on ur.RoleID equals r
                        select u;
        }

        if (hobbyIDs.Count > 0)
        {
            tempUsers = from u in tempUsers
                        join uh in db.User_Hobby on u.UserID equals uh.UserID
                        join h in hobbyIDs on uh.HobbyID equals h
                        select u;
        }

        //Go get it from the database
        Users = ((ObjectQuery<User>)tempUsers)
            .Include("Address").Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```